# vim専用プラグイン管理ツールNeoBundleでプラグインがインストールできない。

Tags: vim

CentOS 6.4でVimを使っており、NeoBundleをインストールしましたが、プラグインがうまくインストールできません。

~/.vimrcの記述は以下になっています。

```
if &compatible
    set nocompatible               " Be iMproved
endif
set runtimepath+=/root/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/
call neobundle#begin(expand('/root/.vim/bundle/'))
NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'

filetype plugin indent on
NeoBundle 'Shougo/unite.vim'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet.vim'
NeoBundle 'joonty/vdebug'
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'

call neobundle#end()
NeoBundleCheck
```

vimを再起動すると以下メッセージが表示され、yを押すのですがプラグインがインストールされません。

```
Not installed bundles:  ['neosnippet.vim', 'vdebug', 'unite.vim',
'nerdtree'] Install bundles now? (y)es, [N]o:
```

コマンドモードでもコマンドが表示されませんし、/.vim/bundle/にもプラグインが入っていません。
ディレクトリの実行権限も一応777にしてます。
何かわかりましたらご教授おねがいします。

Answer (score -1):

> set runtimepath+=/root/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/ call
>   neobundle#begin(expand('/root/.vim/bundle/'))

及び

> ディレクトリの実行権限も一応777にしてます。

と有りますが、

```
$ ls -ld /root
drwxrwxrwx 10 root root 4096 11月 15  2017 /root
```

といった状態なんですよね
これだと危ない気がしますが、これは置いておいて素直に
`/root/.vim/`
ではなく
`~/.vim/`
といったユーザ・ディレクトリにインストールしてはダメなのでしょうか?

あと`/root/.vim/`以下のサブディレクトリに権限がないということもないですよね

Comment: 最初「~/.vim/」にしましたが、ダメでした。調べたら絶対パスの方がいいという情報もありました。  サブディレクトリも再帰的に権限付与してます。